# Understanding the construction た-form+ようになっている

Tags: grammar

琴里もかつて一度、<ファントム>に直接会った経験がある。しかしそのとき<ファントム>は、身体中をノイズのようなものに覆われ、声も変声機を通し**たようになっていた**ため、その実像をまったく掴めなかったのである。

Hi. I have some problems with the bold part. As far as I know, ようになっている is used to describe a resultative state. Whatever grammar book I have checked, however, says we can only use dictionary form before ようになっている, for example, 火事が起こった場合は、このベルは自動的に鳴るようになっています。So I’m not sure about the bold part example. Since た-form is used, the grammar explanation probably doesn’t apply to 通したようになっていた.

So how should I understand this たようになっていた?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

〜ようになっていた means "it was in a state as if 〜 happened". In this case, her voice sounded as if it went through a voice changer (but it hadn't - it just sounded like it had).